# JQ show empty or null values and iterate over different keys

Tags: json, bash, jq

I was looking on how to transform a **`json`** file using `jq` that I receive from a webservice to remove depth levels and keep only some values.

https://jqplay.org/s/_RZNr_oYwE

Json file is similar to this:

```
[
  {
   "date":"2020-04-13",
   "product1":{"p_max":18.00,"p_min":8.00,"interval":[{"time":"06:00:00","price":8.00},{"time":"12:00:00","price":18.00},{"time":"18:00:00","price":16.00},{"time":"24:00:00","price":9.00}]},
   "product2":{"p_max":18.00,"p_min":8.00,"interval":[{"time":"06:00:00","price":8.00},{"time":"12:00:00","price":18.00},{"time":"18:00:00","price":16.00},{"time":"24:00:00","price":9.00}]}
  },
  {
   "date":"2020-04-14",
   "product1":{"p_max":18.00,"p_min":8.00,"interval":[{"time":"06:00:00","price":8.00},{"time":"12:00:00","price":18.00},{"time":"18:00:00","price":16.00},{"time":"24:00:00","price":9.00}]},
   "product2":{"p_max":18.00,"p_min":8.00,"interval":[{"time":"06:00:00","price":9.00},{"time":"12:00:00","price":16.00},{"time":"18:00:00","price":15.00},{"time":"24:00:00","price":11.00}]}
  },
  {
   "date":"2020-04-15",
   "product1":{"p_max":16.00,"p_min":9.00,"interval":[]},
   "product2":{"p_max":16.00,"p_min":9.00,"interval":[]}
  }
]
```

I figured out how to convert the json but I miss some values:

```
jq --compact-output '.[] | .product1.interval[] as $interval| {date: .date, time: ($interval.time//"N/A"), price: ($interval.price//-1)}'
```

This is the output:

```
{"date":"2020-04-13", "time":"06:00:00", "price":8}
{"date":"2020-04-13", "time":"12:00:00", "price":18}
{"date":"2020-04-13", "time":"18:00:00", "price":16}
{"date":"2020-04-13", "time":"24:00:00", "price":9}
{"date":"2020-04-14", "time":"06:00:00", "price":9}
{"date":"2020-04-14", "time":"12:00:00", "price":16}
{"date":"2020-04-14", "time":"18:00:00", "price":15}
{"date":"2020-04-14", "time":"24:00:00", "price":11}
```

But I miss:

```
{"date":"2020-04-15", "time":"N/A", "price":-1}
```

I also have tried but couldn't, so I guess that I will have to iterate in a bash script to get the following output:

```
{"date":"2020-04-13", "time":"06:00:00", "product": "product1", "price":8}
{"date":"2020-04-13", "time":"06:00:00", "product": "product2", "price":4}
{"date":"2020-04-13", "time":"12:00:00", "product": "product1", "price":18}
{"date":"2020-04-13", "time":"12:00:00", "product": "product2", "price":8]
{"date":"2020-04-13", "time":"18:00:00", "product": "product1", "price":16}
{"date":"2020-04-13", "time":"18:00:00", "product": "product2", "price":8}
{"date":"2020-04-13", "time":"24:00:00", "product": "product1", "price":9}
{"date":"2020-04-13", "time":"24:00:00", "product": "product2", "price":5}
{"date":"2020-04-14", "time":"06:00:00", "product": "product1", "price":9}
{"date":"2020-04-14", "time":"06:00:00", "product": "product2", "price":6}
{"date":"2020-04-14", "time":"12:00:00", "product": "product1", "price":16}
{"date":"2020-04-14", "time":"12:00:00", "product": "product2", "price":6}
{"date":"2020-04-14", "time":"18:00:00", "product": "product1", "price":15}
{"date":"2020-04-14", "time":"18:00:00", "product": "product2", "price":15}
{"date":"2020-04-14", "time":"24:00:00", "product": "product1", "price":11}
{"date":"2020-04-14", "time":"24:00:00", "product": "product2", "price":11}
{"date":"2020-04-15", "time":"N/A",      "product": "product1", "price":-1}
{"date":"2020-04-15", "time":"N/A",      "product": "product2", "price":-1}
```

Is there any way to get "empty" values?
Is there any way to produce second output with jq with out needing to iterate on bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to *iterate on bash*, JQ can do that on its own.

Get product names using `keys_unsorted` (which necessitates deleting `date`) and use an `if-then-else` expression for alternating an empty `interval` with `[{"time": "N/A", "price": -1}]`.

```
.[]
| {date} + (
  del(.date)
  | keys_unsorted[] as $product
  | {$product} + (
    .[$product].interval
    | if . == [] then
        {time: "N/A", price: -1}
      else
        .[]
      end
  )
)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/KrVqsLwkqW)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I tried something similar but now I see that it was failing because after the `.[$product].interval` block I needed to add `| .[]` to make it work properly.